# Coleção não permite foreach

Tags: c#, mvc

Tenho uma coleção e dentro tenho outra coleção de imagens. Preciso fazer um foreach encadeado para pegar informações da primeira coleção, e depois o segundo foreach para pegar as imagens que tenho referente ao primeiro looping.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
@foreach ( var item in Model )
{
    <div class="title-pagina-interna">
        <h2>@item.Titulo</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container-carrossel">
        @foreach (Imagem teste in item.Thumb)
```

Porem está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebProvider.MBW_Incentivo.Domain.Models.Imagem' because 'WebProvider.MBW_Incentivo.Domain.Models.Imagem' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

O tipo da propriedade `Thumb` do seu item não é uma coleção de imagens; ela é uma imagem somente, portanto não pode ser usada em um `@foreach`. Como você disse que tem uma coleção de imagens relativa ao item do primeiro loop, você precisa usar a propriedade que retorna essa coleção.

Comment: Ok, mas como faço isso ? Obrigado

Comment: Na sua classe do `Model`, a que contem a propriedade `Thumb` precisa ser, por exemplo: `public List<Imagem> Thumb {get; set;}`. Essa lista vai precisar ser instanciada, claro, e preenchida com as instâncias de `Imagem`, claro, para que a iteração ocorra.